BASH: How to calculate values between two fields in csv/tsv and return output?
I was trying to do some operation over 6th 7th column of a large bed-like file, this is the first 100 rows of the file.
 head -n 100 Sample1.bed
chr1    10000   10150   150 0.506667    0.0503  0.0639
chr1    10002   10144   142 0.507042    0.0308  0.0639
chr1    10003   10139   136 0.507353    0.0246  0.0639
chr1    10008   10156   148 0.513514    0.0375  0.0639
chr1    10012   10138   126 0.500000    0.0156  0.0639
chr1    10013   10194   181 0.497238    0.0737  0.0599
chr1    10016   10169   153 0.509804    0.0503  0.0639
chr1    10031   10161   130 0.507692    0.0205  0.0639
chr1    10038   10211   173 0.502890    0.0968  0.0639
chr1    10044   10179   135 0.511111    0.0246  0.0639
chr1    10071   10145   74  0.500000    0.0001  0.0639
chr1    10071   10240   169 0.508876    0.1022  0.0639
chr1    11178   11334   156 0.679487    0.0704  0.0032
chr1    11561   11733   172 0.418605    0.0968  0.0998
chr1    11597   11776   179 0.435754    0.0867  0.0839
chr1    11641   11796   155 0.432258    0.0704  0.0839
chr1    12218   12376   158 0.651899    0.0704  0.0051
chr1    12368   12551   183 0.617486    0.0737  0.0114
chr1    12486   12658   172 0.645349    0.0968  0.0051
chr1    12770   12952   182 0.582418    0.0737  0.0156
chr1    12813   12943   130 0.561538    0.0205  0.0240
chr1    12870   13043   173 0.583815    0.0968  0.0156
chr1    12882   13089   207 0.599034    0.0214  0.0156
chr1    13378   13569   191 0.581152    0.0463  0.0156
chr1    13381   13592   211 0.578199    0.0160  0.0240
chr1    13435   13580   145 0.593103    0.0375  0.0156
chr1    13515   13688   173 0.578035    0.0968  0.0240
chr1    13550   13705   155 0.574194    0.0704  0.0240
chr1    13808   13944   136 0.514706    0.0246  0.0639
chr1    14004   14174   170 0.529412    0.0968  0.0507
chr1    14231   14393   162 0.580247    0.0884  0.0156
chr1    14249   14385   136 0.588235    0.0246  0.0156
chr1    14262   14432   170 0.523529    0.0968  0.0507
chr1    14267   14409   142 0.549296    0.0308  0.0358
chr1    14272   14385   113 0.584071    0.0070  0.0156
chr1    14288   14451   163 0.527607    0.0884  0.0507
chr1    14291   14425   134 0.522388    0.0205  0.0507
chr1    14316   14481   165 0.509091    0.1022  0.0639
chr1    14556   14768   212 0.622642    0.0160  0.0076
chr1    14635   14830   195 0.656410    0.0365  0.0051
chr1    14654   14795   141 0.673759    0.0308  0.0032
chr1    14786   14931   145 0.579310    0.0375  0.0240
chr1    15073   15258   185 0.643243    0.0585  0.0051
chr1    15078   15223   145 0.627586    0.0375  0.0076
chr1    15113   15279   166 0.632530    0.1022  0.0076
chr1    15286   15512   226 0.584071    0.0069  0.0156
chr1    15353   15482   129 0.565891    0.0156  0.0240
chr1    15379   15545   166 0.560241    0.1022  0.0240
chr1    15440   15692   252 0.595238    0.0027  0.0156
chr1    15478   15648   170 0.594118    0.0968  0.0156
chr1    15492   15659   167 0.592814    0.1022  0.0156
chr1    15633   15776   143 0.685315    0.0308  0.0019
chr1    16119   16267   148 0.601351    0.0375  0.0114
chr1    16478   16646   168 0.488095    0.1022  0.0599
chr1    16786   17014   228 0.618421    0.0069  0.0114
chr1    16818   17069   251 0.609562    0.0027  0.0114
chr1    16843   16999   156 0.628205    0.0704  0.0076
chr1    16947   17105   158 0.563291    0.0704  0.0240
chr1    16951   17078   127 0.551181    0.0156  0.0358
chr1    16961   17148   187 0.572192    0.0585  0.0240
chr1    17076   17216   140 0.614286    0.0308  0.0114
chr1    17149   17311   162 0.617284    0.0884  0.0114
chr1    17259   17442   183 0.562842    0.0737  0.0240
chr1    17327   17518   191 0.638743    0.0463  0.0076
chr1    17335   17522   187 0.641711    0.0585  0.0051
chr1    17386   17556   170 0.652941    0.0968  0.0051
chr1    17432   17598   166 0.698795    0.1022  0.0019
chr1    17546   17662   116 0.646552    0.0093  0.0051
chr1    17547   17682   135 0.637037    0.0246  0.0076
chr1    17587   17728   141 0.595745    0.0308  0.0156
chr1    17729   17940   211 0.630332    0.0160  0.0076
chr1    17729   17967   238 0.634454    0.0043  0.0076
chr1    17871   18115   244 0.655738    0.0036  0.0051
chr1    17880   18038   158 0.683544    0.0704  0.0019
chr1    17906   18074   168 0.672619    0.1022  0.0032
chr1    18146   18318   172 0.593023    0.0968  0.0156
chr1    18269   18432   163 0.595092    0.0884  0.0156
chr1    18328   18518   190 0.621053    0.0463  0.0076
chr1    18392   18568   176 0.619318    0.0867  0.0114
chr1    18417   18600   183 0.601093    0.0737  0.0114
chr1    18432   18652   220 0.590909    0.0088  0.0156
chr1    18516   18663   147 0.578231    0.0375  0.0240
chr1    18521   18709   188 0.558511    0.0585  0.0358
chr1    18588   18751   163 0.539877    0.0884  0.0507
chr1    18618   18770   152 0.546053    0.0503  0.0358
chr1    18897   19067   170 0.594118    0.0968  0.0156
chr1    18906   19084   178 0.584270    0.0867  0.0156
chr1    18958   19165   207 0.545894    0.0214  0.0358
chr1    19131   19303   172 0.622093    0.0968  0.0076
chr1    19192   19372   180 0.661111    0.0737  0.0032
chr1    19244   19394   150 0.653333    0.0503  0.0051
chr1    19271   19409   138 0.652174    0.0246  0.0051
chr1    19371   19525   154 0.558442    0.0503  0.0358
chr1    19452   19654   202 0.549505    0.0282  0.0358
chr1    19476   19683   207 0.560386    0.0214  0.0240
chr1    19479   19621   142 0.514085    0.0308  0.0639
chr1    19497   19638   141 0.553191    0.0308  0.0358
chr1    19777   19965   188 0.579787    0.0585  0.0240
chr1    19795   19943   148 0.547297    0.0375  0.0358
chr1    19797   19924   127 0.551181    0.0156  0.0358

I was using this bash script to do this, however unable to get desired outcome, I'm getting only iScore="nan" . Please correct me where am I going wrong.
    #!/bin/bash
    dir=$1
    file_count=$(ls "$dir" | wc -l)
    for filename in "$dir"/*.bed; do
    parts="${filename##*/}"
    sample_id="${parts%%.*}"
    echo "$sample_id"
    # Filter dataframe based on conditions
    filtered_df="$(awk -F, '($6 > 0 && $6 < 1 && $7 > 0 && $7 < 1)' $filename)"
    echo "$filtered_df"
    # Check if filtered dataframe is not empty
    if [ -n "$filtered_df" ]; then
        # Calculate a and b values
        a=$(echo "$filtered_df" | awk -F, '{print log(1 / ($6 * $7))/log(2)}'  | paste -sd+ - | bc)
        b=$(echo "$filtered_df" | awk -F, '{print log(1 / ((1 - $6) * (1 - $7)))/log(2)}' | paste -sd+ - | bc)
        # Calculate iScore value
        if (( $(echo "$a + $b > 0" | bc -l) )); then
            iScore=$(echo "scale=10; $a / ($a + $b)" | bc)
       else
            iScore="nan"
       fi
    else
       iScore="nan"
    fi
    echo "iScore: $iScore ($sample_id)\n"
    done

Although, when I'm trying manually in the terminal I'm getting the desired result.
Here,  Sample1.csv is first 100 rows of $filtered_df
$ a=$(cat Sample1.csv | awk -F, '{print log(1 / ($6 * $7))/log(2)}'  | paste -sd+ - | bc)
$ b=$(cat Sample1.csv | awk -F, '{print log(1 / ((1 - $6) * (1 - $7)))/log(2)}' | paste -sd+ - | bc)

$ iScore=$(echo "scale=10; $a / ($b + $a)" | bc)
$ echo "$iScore"
$.9842574596


awk can everything in one command, don't club bash into this. You need to show expected output and describe the logic to get it.

The field separator in your .bed file is an arbitrary number of whitespaces; which is not consistent with the comma separator -F, you specify to awk in your bash script.
Try removing the -F, awk delimiter option, which would be useful for a CSV (comma separated values) file but not for your ".bed" file. This way you instruct awk to use it's default field separator (any sequence of space or tab characters).
